# dvdnav-config command not found

Tags: apt, dvd

I installed libdvdnav using the command `sudo apt-get install libdvdnav4`. I tried to run the `dvdnav-config` command but I get a command not found error.I tried uninstalling it and installing it again but ran into the same issue.How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu 12.04 or earlier, then the `dvdnav-config` executable is provided by the development package `libdvdnav-dev` rather than the runtime library package `libdvdnav4`.

If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 or above, then `dvdnav-config` appears to have been removed - according to the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/libd/libdvdnav/libdvdnav_4.2.1-3/changelog):

> Remove dvdnav-config. It breaks multi-arch. Use the dvdnav pkg-config file instead!

Comment: ,Thanks. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 so that explains it. Do you have any idea where I could find the pkg-config file? I searched /usr/lib/pkgconfig but it wasn't there.

Comment: If you install the `libdvdnav-dev` package, it should install a `dvdnav.pc` file in the standard pkgconfig search path. After that it should just be a matter of replacing calls like `dvdnav-config --cflags` by `pkg-config --cflags dvdnav` and so on. If you have a lot of existing projects that depend on `dvdnav-config` you could write a script wrapper for it.